# How to merge data in async pipe in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have showing youtube videos by using async pipe in Angular 6. It's working fine for the first load.

This is how am using it.

**Component HTML file:**

```
<div id="youtube" class="search-results" *ngIf="(trendingVideos | async) as videos; else loadingOrError"></div>
```

Component TS file:

```
public trendingVideos: Observable<VideoClass[]>;
private loadVideos(videosPerPage?: number, regionCode?: string, videoCategoryId?: number) {
      this.trendingVideos = this.youtubeService.getTrendingVideos(videosPerPage, regionCode, videoCategoryId, false)
        .pipe(
          catchError((error: any) => {
            this.loadingError$.next(true);
            return throwError(error);
          })
        );
  }
```

Catch error is working fine also.

**Service File:**

```
public getTrendingVideos(videosPerPage?: number, regionCode?: string, videoCategoryId?: number, paginationMode?: boolean): Observable<VideoClass[]> {
    const params: any = {
      part: appConfig.partsToLoad,
      chart: appConfig.chart,
      videoCategoryId: videoCategoryId ? videoCategoryId : appConfig.defaultCategoryId,
      regionCode: regionCode ? regionCode : appConfig.defaultRegion,
      maxResults: videosPerPage ? videosPerPage : appConfig.maxVideosToLoad,
      key: appConfig.youtubeApiKey
    };
    return this.http.get<any>(appConfig.getYoutubeEndPoint('videos'), { params })
      .pipe(
        map(
          (data) => {
            return data.items
              .map((item) => new VideoClass(item))
              .filter((item) => item.id !== '');
          }
        ),
        catchError(this.handleError('getTrendingVideos'))
      ) as Observable<VideoClass[]>;
  }
```

It's working fine when I load data the first time. Now I am developing infinite scroll. So I am calling this API again. But want to merge data into previously loaded data.

It replaces the data every time with new data when my infinite scroll plugin calls this.

This is infinite scroll function:

```
private onScroll(){
    let videosData:Observable<VideoClass[]> = this.youtubeService.getTrendingVideos(this.videoCount, this.regionCode, this.categoryID, true)
    .pipe(
      catchError((error: any) => {
        this.loadingError$.next(true);
        return throwError(error);
      })
    );
    // Here how i merge this same video data to previously loaded trending videos data.
  }
```

Any Help?

Comment: Try creating an `array` of VideoClass and append the result of api in that array. Use the same`array` to display data in html.

Comment: How i am going to use async pipe with that. @SarthakAggarwal

Comment: You can just use `*ngIf` to check if length of `array` is `0`. If its `0`, it means the data is yet to be retrieved from api. if `length > 0`, you can display the data and on further scrolling, you can call your api and append the data in same array.

Comment: Any way to do using async pipe. @SarthakAggarwal

Comment: In rxjs, if you want to add to the previously returned results, you want to use the scan or mergeScan operator

Answer (score 1):

You just have to use the rxjs map operator and return a new array inside, something like this in your case :

**EDIT:**

Use a behavior subject to get newly videos retrieve by api call.

Here is a live example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-47ndr2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

**component.ts**

```
private videos = [];
private newVideos$ = new BehaviorSubject<VideoClass[]>([]);
public trendingVideos: Observable<VideoClass[]>;

ngOnInit(){
   this.trendingVideos = this.newVideos$.pipe(
     filter(data => data.length > 0),
     map(data => {
        this.videos = [...this.videos, ...data];
        return this.videos;
     });
}
private loadVideos(videosPerPage?: number, regionCode?: string, videoCategoryId?: number) {
  this.youtubeService.getTrendingVideos(videosPerPage, regionCode, videoCategoryId, false)
    .pipe(
      catchError((error: any) => {
        this.loadingError$.next(true);
        return throwError(error);
      })
    ).subscribe(newVideos => this.newVideos$.next(newVideos));
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: It's stop calling API. If I remove map then it starts calling API.

Comment: @KPrananv I updated my answer and add a basic live example on Stackblitz.

Answer (score 1):

Modify Your Infinite scroll as:

```
private onScroll(bufferObj$) {
    return zip(bufferObj$, this.youtubeService.getTrendingVideos(this.videoCount, this.regionCode, this.categoryID, true)
    .pipe(
        catchError((error: any) => {
            this.loadingError$.next(true);
            return throwError(error);
        })
    )).pipe(map((x: any) => x[0].concat(x[1])));
}
```